# Try/Catch seems to work with $_POST but not with session variables, PHP

Tags: php, post, session-variables

I'm working on a `php` tutorial where a thumbnail generation page allows me to select from a dropdown list of photos in a directory on my server and upon hitting the `submit` button, a thumbnail of given size is created using a custom thumbnail class (the thumbnail overwrites the original image, which is fine for what I'm doing now). It's basic stuff and works as expected.

The page code:

```
<?php
$folder = '../images/';

use ClassFiles\Image\Thumbnail;

if (isset($_POST['create'])) {
    require_once('ClassFiles/Image/Thumbnail.php');
    try {
        $thumb = new Thumbnail($_POST['pix']);
        $thumb->setDestination('../images/');
        $thumb->setMaxSize(400);
        $thumb->create();
        $messages = $thumb->getMessages();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Thumb</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
if (isset($messages) && !empty($messages)) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($messages as $message) {
        echo "<li>$message</li>";
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
?>

<form method="post" action="">
    <p>
        <select name="pix" id="pix">
            <option value="">Select an image</option>
            <?php
            $files = new FilesystemIterator('../images/');
            $images = new RegexIterator($files, '/\.(?:jpg|png|gif)$/i');
            foreach ($images as $image) {
                $filename = $image->getFilename();
                ?>
                <option value="<?= $folder . $filename; ?>"><?= $filename; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="create" value="Create Thumbnail">
    </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The custom thumbnail class is lengthy and for the sake of brevity I'm not posting it here unless requested, as it works fine.

So here's the problem:

I decided to take the image path and image filename information from an upload page I've been working on and store them in session variables that could be taken to the thumbnail generation page. The code in the thumbnail generation page was modified as shown:

```
<?php
require_once('includes/session_admin.php');

$folder = $_SESSION['image_path'];

use ClassFiles\Image\Thumbnail;

$getSize = getimagesize($_SESSION['image_path'] . $_SESSION['image_filename']);

$imagePath = $_SESSION['image_path'];
$imageFilename = $_SESSION['image_filename'];

if ($getSize[0] > 400) {
    require_once('ClassFiles/Image/Thumbnail.php');
    try {
        $thumb = new Thumbnail($imageFilename);
        $thumb->setDestination($imagePath);
        $thumb->setMaxSize(400);
        $thumb->create();
        $messages = $thumb->getMessages();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
} else {
    echo "Image is " . $getSize[0] . "px wide and is OK!";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Thumb</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
if (isset($messages) && !empty($messages)) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($messages as $message) {
        echo "<li>$message</li>";
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

// this was just to test that the session variables were correct
echo $_SESSION['image_path'] . $_SESSION['image_filename'];
echo '<br>';
print_r(getimagesize($_SESSION['image_path'] . $_SESSION['image_filename']));
?>
<!--
Removed the form...
-->
</body>
</html>
```

Now, instead of the conditional statement checking to see if `$_POST` was submitted, the code (I thought) would automatically check to see if the image, given the full path and filename, is wider than 400px, and if so, resize the image using the custom thumbnail class.

But, this throws errors from the thumbnail class, the same class that works just fine with the original thumbnail generation page code from the tutorial. 
This works in the original tutorial code:

`$thumb = new Thumbnail($_POST['pix']);`

but not when modified to take a session variable instead:

`$thumb = new Thumbnail($imageFilename);`

I've looked and looked for any suggestion that `$_POST` was required here, I checked that the session variables were passing along the proper information, and they are. But making the switch from `$_POST` to using a session variable prevents this from working.

As you'll see, I'm still learning php and this is one of those hurdles that has held me up all day. Perhaps the answer is glaringly obvious, but I'm certainly at a standstill.

All input is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What's the error message of the exception?

Comment: It throws three of the errors built into the class: `Cannot open image_1.jpg.`, `image_1.jpg doesn't appear to be an image.` and `Cannot determine size of` without displaying the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Try this before set the object of your class
        $_POST['pix']=$_SESSION['image_filename'];
So you set the POST variable manually and use it a The thumbnail class suppose it

Comment: I'd like to omit the `$_POST` altogether. I'm just not certain why the code isn't working with the session variables.

Comment: May be it is because of the thumbnail class itself dealing with the post type variable

Comment: Possibly, but I'm not convinced, nor do I have the expertise to figure that out.